# Find queries with index scans in particular database

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-query-store

How can i find the queries which are index scans in particular database in sql using query store(not dm_exec tables). I need query to find out.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Answer (score 1):

The following query may help to resolve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
        databases.name,
    dm_exec_sql_text.text AS TSQL_Text,
    dm_exec_query_stats.creation_time, 
    dm_exec_query_stats.execution_count,
    dm_exec_query_stats.total_worker_time AS total_cpu_time,
    dm_exec_query_stats.total_elapsed_time, 
    dm_exec_query_stats.total_logical_reads, 
    dm_exec_query_stats.total_physical_reads, 
    dm_exec_query_plan.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dm_exec_query_stats.plan_handle)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(dm_exec_query_stats.plan_handle)
INNER JOIN sys.databases
ON dm_exec_sql_text.dbid = databases.database_id

) AS TMP_TBL WHERE CAST(query_plan AS nvarchar(max)) LIKE '%Clustered Index Scan%'
```